# new UserManager to a different dbcontext

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-core

I need to create a new ASP.NET user account, therefore I need access to the UserManager API. This will give me access to _userManager.CreateAsync() method to allow me to create the account. It's accessed through the constructor as shown below

```
private readonly UserManager<User> _userManager;

public newClientController(UserManager<User> userManager)
{
    _signInManager = signInManager;
}
```

However, this only allows me to access the initial database that the connection string has been configured for. The API changes the connection string as it goes through the controller. However, the _signInManager is connected to the old database. How do I create a new instance of this while connecting to the new dbContext

```
    [HttpGet("CreateNewDb/{dbName}")]
    public void CreateNewDb(string dbName)
    {
        string serverDataString = Startup.StaticConfig
            .GetConnectionString("defaultString");

        var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<DataContext>()
            .UseMySql(serverDataString + dbName, 
            new MySqlServerVersion(new Version(8, 0, 21)));

        DataContext context = new DataContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
        context.Database.Migrate(); 

        // this is the problem here
        UserManager<User> UserManager = new UserManager<User>(context);
```

error message

```
There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'optionsAccessor'
of 'UserManager<User>.UserManager(IUserStore<User>, IOptions<IdentityOptions>, IPasswordHasher<User>, 
IEnumerable<IUserValidator<User>>, IEnumerable<IPasswordValidator<User>>, ILookupNormalizer, 
IdentityErrorDescriber, IServiceProvider, ILogger<UserManager<User>>)'
```

Comment: As far as I know, asp.net core use dependency injection to inject the usermanger, if you just modify the usermanager connection string in just one class method,  it will not affect other controller's usermanager class.  If you want to use another usermanager class, I suggest you could consider register another usermanager class in startup.cs

Comment: How do I modify the usermanager connection string where i am not affecting other usermanagers. it also has to be dynamic. if i register it in startup.cs it will be stuck with that database.